# How to make array from different value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, element

I'm going to filter some countries from `<select id="country" ...>` according their value. I've tried grep and filter in jQuery but not successful. Just for one element it's working ok. 
I don't know how to make correct array in jQuery.

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 function change_country(seldd) {     
    var look_for_id=''; var opt_id=[];
 jQuery('#countries').html("");
 jQuery("#countries").append("<option value='0'>-Country-</option>");
    if(seldd.value=='0') { look_for_id='N'; }   
    if(seldd.value=='1'){ look_for_id='Y';  opt_id=jQuery.filter($("#country option").val(["1,   2, 3, 4"])); }  
    if(seldd.value=='2'){ look_for_id='Y';  opt_id=jQuery.grep(['5', '6', '7', '8']); }  
    if(look_for_id=='Y') {
 jQuery("#country option[value='"+opt_id+"']").each(function() {
 jQuery("#countries").append("<option   value='"+jQuery(this).val()+"'>"+jQuery(this).text()+"</option>");
  });
 } else {
 jQuery("#country option").each(function() {
 jQuery("#countries").append("<option  value='"+jQuery(this).val()+"'>"+jQuery(this).text()+"</option>");
    });
  }  
 }

 <div>      
<select id="region" id="srv_type" onchange="change_fruit(this)" >
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Регион</option>
  <option value="1">Asia</option>
  <option value="2">Europe</option>
</select>  </div> 

<div style="display:none;" >   
<select id="country" name="country" class="inputbox">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Страна</option>
   <option value="1" >Indonesia</option>
   <option value="2">Thailand</option>
   <option value="3">Singapore</option>
   <option value="4">Malaysia</option>
   <option value="5">Greece</option>
   <option value="6">Italy</option>
   <option value="7">Monaco</option>
   <option value="8">Spain</option>
</select>
</div>
<select name="countries" id="countries">
   <option value="0">-Country-</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think you tried it to complicated. Just mark your values with a class and select them by the class name. See my example below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a jquery array is the same as a javascript array.e.g.

```
thing = [];
```

or

```
thing = new Array();
```

If you add things to your array e.g.

```
countries = ['UK','USA','etc'];
```

you can the loop though them using jquery .each or a for loop. You could also have an array of arrays e.g.

```
thing = [['UK','Europe'],['USA','North America']];
```

then loop through the main array and access the other elements via their index.

thing[0][0] would output UK.

Just did a quick google and this might help you:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

It shows some of the other things you can do with arrays

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var a = [];

$("#country option").each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('value') > 5){
  a.push($(this).text());
  }
});
```

Comment: Dear Miro, I'm newest in jQuery, could you explain to me in more detailed manner please. How to assign <option value="1">Asia</option> to  <option value="1" >Indonesia</option>
   <option value="2">Thailand</option>
   <option value="3">Singapore</option>
   <option value="4">Malaysia</option> for example.

Comment: My listing have not ordering like in sample and looks like this <option value="15">Bahams</option>
 <option value="73">Greece</option>
 <option value="86">India</option>
 <option value="92">Italy</option>
 <option value="35">Canada</option>
 <option value="115">France</option>
 <option value="194">USA</option>
 <option value="181">Turkey</option>

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just make a subselect of country based on the area you selected. Try this one instead:

```
<select id="region" name="region">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Регион</option>
  <option value="country_as">Asia</option>
  <option value="country_eu">Europe</option>
</select>
<select id="country" name="country">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Страна</option>
   <option value="1" class="country_as" >Indonesia</option>
   <option value="2" class="country_as">Thailand</option>
   <option value="3" class="country_as">Singapore</option>
   <option value="4" class="country_as">Malaysia</option>
   <option value="5" class="country_eu">Greece</option>
   <option value="6" class="country_eu">Italy</option>
   <option value="7" class="country_eu">Monaco</option>
   <option value="8" class="country_eu">Spain</option>
</select>
```

with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#region").change(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $("#country > option ").each(function(){ $(this).hide();});
        $("."+v).each(function(){ $(this).show();});
    });
});​
```

you can [test this on js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsGwK/)

**EDIT**

[This DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hsGwK/2/) is a better version with following jQuery Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#region").change(function() {
        $("[class^=country_]").each(function(){ $(this).hide();});
        $("."+$(this).val()).each(function(){ $(this).show();});
    });
});​
```